# How do I iterate over a local array in a remote ssh bash command

Tags: arrays, bash, ssh, iteration

I need to perform several copy commands on a remote location (using ssh "cp blah blah2"). Instead of having a separate ssh connection for each command, I would like to do something like:

```
dirs=(dir1 dir2 dir3)
for dir in ${dirs[*]} ; do echo $dir; done
ssh user@server "for dir in ${dirs[*]}; do echo $dir; cp some/file.txt /home/user/$dir/; done"
```

But even though the first echo prints all three dirs, the echos performed on the remote server are all equal to the last dir value ("dir3"). I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, or why it's printing three echos (and doing three copies), when it's only using the same value. I guess it has something to do with when the variables are expanded (locally or remotely)...

I've tried using dirs="dir1 dir2 dir3", @ instead of *, quotings, but I haven't been able to find a combination that works.

Anyone have any experience with this problem? :)

Cheers,
  Svend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` loop you execute before calling ssh creates a $dir varible and your shell expands it, so you are actually executing:

```
    ssh user@server "for dir in dir1 dir2 dir3; do echo dir3; cp some/file.txt /home/user/dir3/; done"
```

**You should escape $** to avoid shell expansion. Try:

```
dirs="dir1 dir2 dir3"
ssh user@server "for dir in $dirs ; do echo \$dir; cp some/file.txt /home/user/\$dir/; done"
```

In this example, `$dirs` is a local variable and `$dir` is a remote variable. Your shell will replace $dirs in your command BEFORE executing ssh, so you will be really executing:

```
ssh user@server "for dir in dir1 dir2 dir3; do echo \$dir; cp some/file.txt /home/user/\$dir/; done"
```

Comment: I would have thought the first one would definitely work (while not being ideal, as my dir array may be quite large), but it doesn't seem to. I even tried this: `ssh user@server "for dir in dir1 dir2 dir3; do echo $dir; done"` and that gives the same result (dir3\ndir3\ndir3)... :(

Comment: To avoid shell intereferences, escape your variables with a backslash before each dollar as in my examples. `$dir` --> `\$dir`

Comment: Sorry, didn't spot that :) Thank you!

Comment: @FranciscoR - That seems to work with the array loop syntax: myArray="onething anotherthing"; ssh thufirg-0105 "for myValue in ${myArray[@]}; do echo \$myValue; done;" but it does not seem to work when using a loop counter?:  myArray="onething anotherthing"; ssh thufirg-0105 "for ((i=0; i<2; i++ )); do
echo ${myArray[\$i]};
done;" ?